# Requirements on dielectric strength and isolation between the conductors in an Ethernet transmission line with PoE

Tags: ethernet, isolation, poe

I am trying to find out what the requirements are on dielectric strength and isolation between the conductors in a Gigabit Ethernet transmission line.

**A first place to look** would of course be the [TIA-568 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TIA/EIA-568), but I can't afford to buy it.

**Second place to look** would be in a manufacturers datasheet for a Cat5e cable like [this](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1311844.pdf) one, which specifies the following:

> Dielectric strength conductor-conductor and conductor-screen (2 seconds) : 2.5 kV DC

That's what I'm looking for, but the problem with this is that the manufacturer might have taken some headroom over the minimum value allowed by any possible standard. So that's a dead end, as I see it.

Are there requirements on this property in any standard? If so, which one and where to find it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should be able to deduce them from the used voltages

Comment: @PlasmaHH Those voltage levels are known, but I'm looking for any possible universal requirement regulated by some standard.

Comment: What is the insulation rating on the cables between conductors? Compare and cross refer this with the breakdown voltages specified for the magnetics.

Comment: @Andyaka That is a good start, but I haven't been able to find that either. Is it in the TIA-568 standard perhaps? I can't afford to buy the standard though...

Comment: Go look at manufacturer's data sheets to get the values.

Comment: @Andyaka While that is a sound strategy for specifying a value that will comply with standards, it doesn't solve problem/answer the question.

Comment: If there is a standard anywhere to be found then the data sheets of the cables and the magnetic componets would surely reference them so get looking is my advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the leads are connected to each other at the termination there is no requirement on dielectric strength between the conductors, only between the shield and the 8 leads of the cable.